# Issue with sources, 404 on upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, dist-upgrade

on Debian Bullseye (11) I recently have run into some dead endpoints when I run `apt dist-upgrade` after an `update`, see my sources list below. I have tried to resolve with `--fix-missing` and I have run `apt clean`... Any ideas?

I have looked at the site, http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/, and I can confirm the directories are missing.

Errors

```
Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.31-13_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-i386_2.31-13_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.31-13_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.31-13_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-13_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.32_5.32.1-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.32.1-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/perl-base_5.32.1-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mutter/mutter_3.38.4-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mutter/libmutter-7-0_3.38.4-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus_3.38.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus-data_3.38.2-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/exiv2/libexiv2-27_0.27.3-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/grilo/libgrilo-0.3-0_0.3.13-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_12.21.0%7edfsg-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nodejs/libnode72_12.21.0%7edfsg-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.53.3%7edfsg-7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript/libgs9-common_9.53.3%7edfsg-7_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/flatpak/flatpak_1.10.2-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-extension-prefs_3.38.4-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speech-dispatcher/speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng_0.10.2-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speech-dispatcher/speech-dispatcher_0.10.2-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speech-dispatcher/speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins_0.10.2-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:10::644 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Sources

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Why do you have "buster" in your `sources.list` instead of "bullseye"? Have you tried changing that and redoing `apt update`?

Comment: @Bytor - ya after Stephen mentioned the security bit I realized that I needed to update my other sources as well. It was all out of whack. Thanks for mentioning as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apt update` is either too old or didn’t complete successfully; the current Debian 11 version of glibc packages is 2.31-13+deb11u2, not 2.13-13.

Note that your `sources.list` is missing the Debian 11 security repositories:

```
deb http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free
```